# Deploy and update .net assembly with clickonce

Tags: .net, clickonce

Want to deploy and auto-update my .net assembly.
But publishing is only for winforms and wpf applications.

Found solution: create empty winforms application, add .net assembly as content, make form invisible, and deploy this app. And here will be troubles with upgrade..

Is it best solution?

Comment: What purpose is this serving? ClickOnce will install the assembly into a per-user folder that isn't very discoverable. Have you consider NuGet instead?

Comment: point is, this dll invoked by unmanaged win32 app

Comment: How does the app know where to find the assembly?

Comment: it's com visible, and it's actually registred and located in folder with app, but now i want to add ability to make auto update at users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the ClickOnce install invoked by another application in order to check for updates. So whatever application is using the assembly can just do a process.start on the URL to the installation URL and it will do the update.